# android java 2 observable , single

Tags: android

I am trying to create a new LocationViewModel by passing a single location and a visitCount for that location in the costructor, but for this i am first getting all location and then for every location i am trying to get a visitCount

```
addDisposable(mLocationProvider.getLocation()
            .flatMapSingle(locations -> Flowable.fromIterable(locations)
                    .flatMapSingle(singleLocation -> mVisitCountRepo.requestVisitCount(singleLocation.getId()))
                    .toList())
            .subscribe(visitCountList -> {


            }, Throwable::printStackTrace));
```

The issue is that i don't know how to combine the two so i can have something like:

```
flatMapSinge(singleLocation,visitCount -> new LocationViewModel(singleLocation,visitCount).toList()
```

Currently i am getting List at the end, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either use Map or Pair class to return visitCount and location and omit result one by one instead of a list.

Here I attached simple kotlin and Java code of pair class maybe it help you.

**Kotlin class**

```
Observable.just("Will")
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .flatMap({ name ->
    updateUserName.execute(name) //returns another Observable<ApiResult> after calling the API
  }, {
    //this is executed after resolving the last observable emitted, so the result is ready.
     name: String, apiResult: ApiResult -> Pair(name, apiResult) 
  })
  .subscribe({ result ->
    result.first //name
    result.second //apiResult
  })
```

**Java Class:**

```
bservable.just("foo")
          .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Integer>>() {
              @Override
              public Observable<Integer> call(String foo) {
                  return Observable.range(1, 5);
              }
          }, new Func2<String, Integer, Pair<Integer, String>>() {
              @Override
              public Pair<Integer, String> call(String s, Integer i) {
                  return new Pair<>(i, s);
              }
          })
          .subscribe(new Action1<Pair<Integer, String>>() {
              @Override
              public void call(Pair<Integer, String> pair) {
                  System.out.println("Result: " + pair.first + " Foo: " + pair.second);
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a List of `LocationViewModel` at the end like this

```
  addDisposable(mLocationProvider.getLocation().flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)
            .flatMap(singleLocation -> mVisitCountRepo.requestVisitCount(singleLocation.getId()).toFlowable()
                    .map(visitCount -> new LocationViewModel(singleLocation, visitCount)))
            .toList()
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<LocationViewModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<LocationViewModel> locationViewModels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            }));
```